# Neo4j - rails console - can't wait on resource RWLock error

Tags: neo4j

Getting this error from the rails console:

```
a = Author.first
Neo4j::Server::CypherResponse::ResponseError: LockClient[12] can't wait on resource RWLock[SCHEMA(0), hash=1915081964] since => LockClient[12] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[SCHEMA(0), hash=1915081964] <-[:WAITING_FOR]- LockClient[3] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[SCHEMA(0), hash=1915081964]
```

Server is up and runing, able to execute any query from the database console, or from the database browser interface.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Did you just start the console?  Do you have anything happening on initialize of your Rails app?  Are you using server or embedded mode?  What version of the gem are you using?

Comment: The error disappeared after I restarted the server. This is a development environment. The db is hosted in AWS.

Comment: neo4j (4.1.5)
neo4j-core (4.0.7)

Comment: The rails server is local to my computer.

Comment: All the statements today were of type "read", no "writes" performed.

Comment: I restarted the rails server and got same error for this:

b = Bisac.find_by(bisac_code: 'POL019000')
Neo4j::Server::CypherResponse::ResponseError: LockClient[39] can't wait on resource RWLock[SCHEMA(0), hash=670957984] since => LockClient[39] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[SCHEMA(0), hash=670957984] <-[:WAITING_FOR]- LockClient[28] <-[:HELD_BY]- RWLock[SCHEMA(0), hash=670957984]
 from /Users/levi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/neo4j-core-4.0.7/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_response.rb:161:in `raise_error'

Comment: The similar cypher query from the neo4j console or browser interface returns without problems, see below:

$ match (b:Bisac{bisac_code: 'POL019000'}) return b.bisac_code, b.bisac_value;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| b.bisac_code | b.bisac_value                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "POL019000"  | "POLITICAL SCIENCE / Public Policy / Social Services & Welfare" |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking a bit I realized/remembered that there are some changes on master which deal with this:

https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/issues/732

Try changing your `Gemfile` to this:

```
gem 'neo4j', github: 'neo4jrb/neo4j'
gem 'neo4j-core', github: 'neo4jrb/neo4j-core'
```

We're planning on cutting a release candidate next week, so if this works for you you won't need to run off master for long

Comment: Changed the gemfile, executed bundle, restarted the rails server, restarted the database server.

Comment: Here are the new errors:
a = Author.find_by(author_name: 'Camus, Albert')
ArgumentError: The 'type' option must be specified( even if it is `nil`) or `origin`/`rel_class` must be specified (Class#wokas)
 from /Users/levi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/neo4j-52306e68783c/lib/neo4j/active_node/has_n.rb:335:in `validate_association_options!'
 from /Users/levi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/neo4j-52306e68783c/lib/neo4j/active_node/has_n.rb:295:in `has_many'

Comment: Or this:
w = Woka.find_by(woka_title: 'Pes, Die')
ArgumentError: The 'type' option must be specified( even if it is `nil`) or `origin`/`rel_class` must be specified (Class#author)
 from /Users/levi/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/neo4j-52306e68783c/lib/neo4j/active_node/has_n.rb:335:in `validate_association_options!'

Comment: Yup, that's an exception that's part of the new release.  All of your associations must have either a 'type', 'origin', or 'rel_class' key in the options.  There were a lot of people writing to us with issues that let back to making sure that the `type` was set, and you pretty much always want to set it.  If you want the old default behavior of having the gem choose an association for you you can specify a `nil` value

Comment: OK, here is my Author class, please let me know how to change it.

class Author
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  property :author_name,  type: String
  property :author_id,    type: Integer

  has_many :out, :wokas
end

Comment: Your `wokas` association needs to have a type which determines the relationship type that will be used inside of Neo4j.  If you've been working with Neo4j.rb successfully you can set `has_many :out, :wokas, type: nil`, though you might think about setting the type explicitly like `has_many :out, :wokas, type: :whatever_type_you_want`

Comment: Also keep in mind that the default behavior is to capitalize the relationship type.  This can be changed with the `transform_rel_type` configuration option (see: http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Configuration.html ).  IMPORTANT NOTE: That documentation isn't finished yet.  I hope to have it ready for a production-ready release of the 5.0 version of the gem

Comment: OK, here is what I did. I changed to this has_many :out, :wokas, type: 'authored' considering that the relationship in the database is AUTHORED. Seems that things are working. Is my approach correct?

Comment: Yup!  That seems like a great approach!

Comment: Change all my classes to include type and everything works well now.

Comment: Great, thanks.  Let us know if you find any other issues with master and keep an eye on rubygems for the release candidate version next week

Comment: Thank you, I will proceed as recommended.